# State a controller action on a view from different project within the same solution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

What is the correct way to call an action that is defined in a different project inside a view ?

```
<a asp-controller="Cities" asp-action="IndexJson" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1 ripple" aria-current="true">
```

[image]

Comment: Does that action of city controller returns view or json result?

Comment: It Returns a view

Comment: So you want to call city Controller action in layout in main page right?

Comment: Yes this what i want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try as below in program.cs:

```
using AnotherProj.Controllers;
```

......

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews( ).AddApplicationPart(typeof(AnotherController).Assembly);
```

Add the reference:

[image]
The result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you referenced AnotherController in program.cs ?

Comment: add the reference of the  anotherproj Project and referred the namespace

Comment: I've updated my answe,you could check it now